# What's a good temporal distance to no longer display relative dates?

Tags: language-agnostic, datetime, date, time

Relative dates are great to display the temporal incidence of recent activity, but at what distance is it an inconvenience for the user to see a relative date rather than an absolute one?

Let's assume the context is a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely relevant to whatever the dates are associated with.  If it's an update feed (like your SO recent activity), then it may be a good idea to display relative dates by the hour.  If it's articles talking about software updates, then days would be more appropriate...

Answer (score 1):

For me, a week is about the limit.  I don't know of any industrial pysch studies to support it.

Answer (score 1):

I just display today and yesterday as relative dates, like facebook does.

3 days ago makes me wonder which day it was, and I find it confusing.
Not to mention Flickr's "three months ago" without any detailed info :(